# Web scraping - handling non fatal errors

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using web scrapers (bs4, selenium) and wondering if there is a better way to handle exceptions that are not fatal (i.e. continue running after exception).

There are a *lot* of try excepts in my code for every property and I would like to centralize that logic.

Note productDetails is an instance of ProductDetails which has setter and getter python properties. I thought about putting the except logic in the setter but by then it is too late because the request has to get the value first.

```
try:
    productDetails.image = soup.find("meta", property="og:image")[
except:
    productDetails.url_valid = False
    continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors should never pass silently.
I suggest you handle all exceptions explicitly. Finally, avoid putting the except logic in the setter or getter methods.